# Работа с строкой RowDataBound

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Пользователь кликает по GridView1. Каким образом перехватить событие клика и узнать по какой строке кликнули?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватить событие клика можно только на клиенте. И обработать - тоже. Поэтому разбирайтесь с клиентскими библиотеками.

Самой простой в освоении считается [JQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$("#ИдВашейТаблицы").on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    // Здесь event.currentTarget - это та строка, на которую кликнул пользователь
})
```

Правда, это лишь [элемент DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement), который сам по себе говорит очень мало. Чтобы получить хоть какие-нибудь данные из строки, надо их куда-нибудь записать, чтобы потом извлечь. Проще всего записать их в невидимую колонку.

---

PS если будет больше задач по клиентскому программированию - обдумайте перспективы перехода на ASP.NET MVC и ASP.NET WebPages (Razor). Там многое делается куда проще.

Или можно вообще перейти на клиентскую шаблонизацию с такими технологиями как AngularJs, Knockout или React Js.

Comment: Идея с JQuery звучит достаточно интересно, жаль сам не подумал об этом. А вот делаем переход на другую *.aspx страницу через JQuery - может ли принимающая страница словить передающий параметр? (Кроме как через строку).

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron Параметр можно передать через строку запроса или через данные POST. Во втором случае создается форма (заранее или прямо скриптом), после чего ей делается submit.

Comment: Форма должна быть скрытой, верно?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron да. Кстати, будьте осторожнее если собираетесь "укладывать" форму заранее, на стороне сервера. Форма внутри формы иногда работает очень странным образом (мне в том числе из-за этой проблемы пришлось переписывать jquery file upload plugin).

Comment: Я хочу взять из GridView1 по клику строку, из нее получить значение первого столбика - номер id. Как мне получить это значение из event.currentTarget? Не смог сам разобратся с JQuery

Comment: Я давал вам ссылку на MDN, описывающий объект DOM. Чтобы получить первую ячейку, надо у него взять `cells[0]`. Текст первой ячейки - `cells[0].innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

[GridView.SelectedIndexChanging Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Это Select если кнопку кликнут. А мне нужно так, что если по любой ячейке строки кликнут.